# How to import data from ms sql to tabular model using .NET

Tags: .net, azure, import, ssas

So is it possible to import data from ms sql to tabular model ssas using .net library adom.net? For now I know it is possible using wizard of data import, but maybe there is possible to do it without using wizard, but making with .net?

Comment: You can't push data into a tabular model. You can only connect to the server and tell it to "process" (pull data). See if this helps.... it's not a very helpful question but it should give you a rough idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575563/process-ssas-cube-through-c-sharp-code

Comment: Are you trying to add a data source to an existing model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you are trying to do a data refresh or add a whole new datasource to your model. However, either one is fairly straightforward with the .net libraries.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server();

        server.Connect("Data source=YourSSASServerName;Timeout=7200000;Integrated Security=SSPI");

        Database database = server.Databases.FindByName("YourCubeDBName");

        //
        //process database (load in fresh data from SQL)
        //
        database.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);





        //
        // add new data source to model (SQL server)
        //
        database.Model.DataSources.Add(new ProviderDataSource()
        {
            Name = "SQL Server Data Source Example",
            Description = "A data source definition that uses explicit Windows credentials for authentication against SQL Server.",
            ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=false",
            ImpersonationMode = Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ImpersonationMode.ImpersonateAccount,
            Account = @".\Administrator",
            Password = "P@ssw0rd",
        });


        // 
        // Add the new database object to the server's  
        // Databases connection and submit the changes 
        // with full expansion to the server. 
        // 
        server.Databases.Add(database);
        database.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);
    }
```